# slide down click event jQuery searchbox

Tags: jquery, search, input, slidedown, slideup

on browser window 550px width (mobile view):

i will to implement: if i click on the search icon the search input slide down and if i click again on the search icon the search input slide up and i don't see this.

Here my Click Event:

```
jQuery('#searchbutton').click(function(){

        });
```

Here is my Testsite:

http://devel.hoevermann-gruppe.de/

Example (550px width browser window): www.microsoft.com

Comment: You don't actually have any code in your function... have you looked at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) for `slideToggle`? There are full examples there that should give you exactly what you need.

Comment: jQuery("#search_icon").click(function(){
            $('.search_mobil').slideToggle();
        });

Comment: But it doesn't work good ;(

Comment: It would help if you told us what part didn't work. Can you provide a fiddle with what you've tried? I just created one [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YXwwd/) and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<a href="#">Click</a><br>
<input id="toggle" type="text">
```

CSS:

```
#toggle{
    display:none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$("a").click(function(){
  $("#toggle").slideToggle();
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/bQkMW/)